# Git pull removes/deletes local files

Tags: git, pull

When I **git add -A** and then **git commit -m** then **git status** the results are:

**Your branch and 'origin/gh-pages' have diverged,
and have 1 and 1 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)**

I then do a **git pull**, the result is a bunch of files that where previously committed and pushed are now removed from my local repository?

Nobody else is working in this repository and I've recently done **pulls** without this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are on the correct branch?  You might try `git log --graph --abbrev-commit --decorate --format=format:'%C(bold blue)%h%C(reset) - %C(bold green)(%ar)%C(reset) %C(white)%s%C(reset) %C(dim white)- %an%C(reset)%C(bold yellow)%d%C(reset)' --all`.  (I have this command aliased to `git graph`.)

Comment: Files are not removed from the *repository*. They're removed from your *working tree*. The repository contains commits; the commits contain files. Git only *adds new commits*, without removing existing ones, unless you force it to drop commits (and you're not doing that). So the commits still exist, and still hold the files. It's the fact that the new commits you picked up say "don't have this file", while the older commit you're using says "do have this file", that makes Git remove the file from your working tree, which is the area where the files *in* the commits are *copied to*.

Comment: All this is a lot of technical distinctions that might not matter for what you want to get done, but the thing is, they *do* matter for actually *getting it done*. :-) Git forces you to learn all this stuff.

Comment: I would ultimately like to just reset to my current local.

Comment: git push --force to the rescue!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the diff introduced in `origin/gh-pages` :

```
git show origin/gh-pages

# or a shorter output which lists which files were modified :
git show --name-status origin/gh-pages
```

Chances are this last commit removed said files.

---

About "fixing" : check why that extra commit landed on your remote repo (since you say you are the only one to work on that repo, you should be the one who pushed it).

If that commit is the result of some wrong operation : drop that commit (perhaps you can `push --force` your current local branch ?) or edit that commit to fix it :

```
git checkout -b wip origin/gh-pages
# some fixing here ...
git push origin wip:gh-pages  # possibly with the --force flag
```

Comment: Assuming the D represents deleted, you would be correct, the files were deleted. But I didn't delete them? More importantly than determining this, how can I resolve this issue. I've done a git reset --hard HEAD@{0} to return my local repository to the correct state but if I do a pull they will be removed again?

Comment: git push --force was what I need confirmation on, thanks!!!

Comment: After doing git push --force I thought everything would be synced with remote. At this point I made another change to local code, add -A, commit -m and pull. Local files are removed after pull again???

Comment: Run `git fetch` instead of `git pull`, and `git log --oneline --graph HEAD @{u}` to have a view of your branch and its remote counterpart.